# Is there a chance that a button can affect the CSS flex basis property?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have this problem where the flex basis size was changed based on the button size. It would be helpful if someone help me to clear this problem.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f2ebe3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#container {
  width: 375px;
  height: 630px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

#back-image img {
  width: 375px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#p1 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#h1 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
}

#h2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: -5%;
  font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
}

#p2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#price-container {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#price-container h1 {
  font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
  color: #3c8067;
}

#price-container p {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3c8067;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #2F5951
}

.cart {
  margin-right: 10px
}

@media (min-width:576px) {
  #container {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1440px;
    max-height: 400px;
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-right: 30%;
  }
  #container-2 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  #back-image img {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  }
  #btn {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Semi+Condensed:wght@500&family=Karla&family=League+Spartan:wght@100&family=Montserrat:wght@500&family=Red+Hat+Display:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Semi+Condensed:wght@500&family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,700&family=Karla&family=League+Spartan:wght@100&family=Montserrat:wght@500&family=Red+Hat+Display:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Product preview card component</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="back-image">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1672197339033-688e27f884f2?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="Product image" />
    </div>
    <div id="container-2">
      <p id="p1">P E R F U M E</p>
      <h2 id="h1">Gabrielle Essence</h2>
      <h2 id="h2">Eau De Parfum</h2>
      <p id="p2">
        A floral, solar and voluptuous <br /> interpretation composed by Olivier <br /> Polge, Perfumer-Creator for the House of <br /> CHANEL.
      </p>
      <div id="price-container">
        <h1>$149.99</h1>
        <p>$169.99</p>
      </div>

      <button id="btn">
          <img class="cart" src="images/icon-cart.svg" alt="" />
          Add to Cart
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to reduce the size of the button while changing the size of the button, and the flex-basis ratio also changed. I don't know why. Can anyone help me to clear this up?

Answer (score 0):

Did few changes like added `flex-basis: 50%` to `#back-image` instead of `#back-image img`, added `justify-content: space-between` and `align-items: center` to `#container-2` for media query.

Though if you increase button size beyond initial 50% of `container` size, `flex-basis` for `container-2` may grow as well.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f2ebe3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
}

#container {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

#container-2 {
  padding-block-end: 1em;
}

#back-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#p1 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#h1 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
}

#h2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: -5%;
  font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
}

#p2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#price-container {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#price-container h1 {
  font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
  color: #3c8067;
}

#price-container p {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 5rem;
  height: fit-content;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #3c8067;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #2F5951
}

.cart {
  margin-right: 10px
}

@media (min-width:576px) {
  #container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 1440px;
    max-height: 400px;
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-right: 30%;
  }
  #container-2 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    padding-block-end: 1em;
  }
  #back-image {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 0%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  }
  #btn {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="back-image">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEKnuXARsxMe34S8gF8HM_KISj3yDVF1MCcTa4ZBTiIHPTZauH2QrLA5DNME3bBzTx5O8&usqp=CAU" alt="Product image" />
  </div>
  <div id="container-2">
    <p id="p1">P E R F U M E</p>
    <h2 id="h1">Gabrielle Essence</h2>
    <h2 id="h2">Eau De Parfum</h2>
    <p id="p2">
      A floral, solar and voluptuous <br /> interpretation composed by Olivier <br /> Polge, Perfumer-Creator for the House of <br /> CHANEL.
    </p>
    <div id="price-container">
      <h1>$149.99</h1>
      <p>$169.99</p>
    </div>

    <button id="btn">
          <img class="cart" src="images/icon-cart.svg" alt="" />
          Add to Cart
        </button>
  </div>
</div>
```